# What is the most efficient algorithm to find pixel clusters and draw bbox

Tags: python, numpy, computer-vision, object-detection, bounding-box

I have the following scenario, I have a N*N binary image and I want to find the number of clusters and draw bbox around them.

A few requirements:
 - There is at least 1 cluster, there could be many.
 - The only parameter "controlable" is **k** being the maximum distance between pixels belonging to same cluster.

Here is some code to show what I am talking about:

### 1. Generate a random image with 6 clusters (just a random example)

**Note:** I don't want to improve this part, this is just for example.

```
import numpy as np

from PIL import Image
from IPython.display import display

def display_array(image):
    image_display_ready = (image * 255).astype(np.uint8)

    img = Image.fromarray(image_display_ready)
    display(img)

def generate_image():
    image = np.zeros([256,256])

    for _ in range(200):
        while True:
            i, j = np.random.randint(25, 100, size=2)

            if image[i, j] == 0:
                break

        image[i, j] = 1

    for _ in range(200):
        while True:
            i, j = np.random.randint(150, 225, size=2)

            if image[i, j] == 0:
                break

        image[i, j] = 1

    for _ in range(100):
        while True:
            i, j = (np.random.randint(150, 225), np.random.randint(25, 50))

            if image[i, j] == 0:
                break

        image[i, j] = 1

    for _ in range(100):
        while True:
            i, j = (np.random.randint(150, 225), np.random.randint(75, 100))

            if image[i, j] == 0:
                break

        image[i, j] = 1

    for _ in range(100):
        while True:
            i, j = (np.random.randint(25, 50), np.random.randint(150, 225))

            if image[i, j] == 0:
                break

        image[i, j] = 1

    for _ in range(100):
        while True:
            i, j = (np.random.randint(75, 100), np.random.randint(150, 225))

            if image[i, j] == 0:
                break

        image[i, j] = 1

    return image

image = generate_image() 
display_array(image)
```

#### Output:

[image]

### 2. Find the number of clusters

Below is the solution, I currently have, I would like to know if it can be improved. It doesn't look like *an efficient solution* to me.

**Note:** `lookup_range` is the `k` parameter introduced earlier

```
def compute_bbox_coordinates(mask_img, lookup_range, verbose=0):

    bbox_list = list()
    visited_pixels = list()

    bbox_found = 0

    for i in range(mask_img.shape[0]):
        for j in range(mask_img.shape[1]):

            if mask_img[i, j] == 1 and (i, j) not in visited_pixels:

                bbox_found += 1

                pixels_to_visit = list()

                bbox = {
                    'i_min': i,
                    'j_min': j,
                    'i_max': i,
                    'j_max': j
                }

                pxl_i = i
                pxl_j = j

                while True:

                    visited_pixels.append((pxl_i, pxl_j))

                    bbox['i_min'] = min(bbox['i_min'], pxl_i)
                    bbox['j_min'] = min(bbox['j_min'], pxl_j)
                    bbox['i_max'] = max(bbox['i_max'], pxl_i)
                    bbox['j_max'] = max(bbox['j_max'], pxl_j)

                    i_min = max(0, pxl_i - lookup_range)
                    j_min = max(0, pxl_j - lookup_range)

                    i_max = min(mask_img.shape[0], pxl_i + lookup_range + 1)
                    j_max = min(mask_img.shape[1], pxl_j + lookup_range + 1)

                    for i_k in range(i_min, i_max):
                        for j_k in range(j_min, j_max):

                            if mask_img[i_k, j_k] == 1 and (i_k, j_k) not in visited_pixels and (
                            i_k, j_k) not in pixels_to_visit:
                                pixels_to_visit.append((i_k, j_k))
                                visited_pixels.append((i_k, j_k))

                    if not pixels_to_visit:
                        break

                    else:
                        pixel = pixels_to_visit.pop()
                        pxl_i = pixel[0]
                        pxl_j = pixel[1]

                bbox_list.append(bbox)
    if verbose:
        print("BBOX Found: %d" % bbox_found)

    return bbox_list

bbox_coords = compute_bbox_coordinates(image, lookup_range=15, verbose=0)
print(bbox_coords)
```

#### Output:

```
Number of clusters: 6
[
    {'i_min': 25, 'j_min': 25, 'i_max': 99, 'j_max': 99}, 
    {'i_min': 25, 'j_min': 150, 'i_max': 49, 'j_max': 224}, 
    {'i_min': 75, 'j_min': 151, 'i_max': 99, 'j_max': 224}, 
    {'i_min': 150, 'j_min': 75, 'i_max': 224, 'j_max': 99}, 
    {'i_min': 150, 'j_min': 150, 'i_max': 224, 'j_max': 224}, 
    {'i_min': 151, 'j_min': 25, 'i_max': 224, 'j_max': 49}
]
```

### 3. Compute the bbox overlay from the bbox coordinates

```
def compute_bbox_overlay(target_image, bbox_list):

    mask_img_bbox = np.copy(target_image)

    for bbox in bbox_list:
        mask_img_bbox[bbox['i_min'], bbox['j_min']:bbox['j_max']+1] = 1
        mask_img_bbox[bbox['i_max'], bbox['j_min']:bbox['j_max']+1] = 1
        mask_img_bbox[bbox['i_min']:bbox['i_max']+1, bbox['j_min']] = 1
        mask_img_bbox[bbox['i_min']:bbox['i_max']+1, bbox['j_max']] = 1

    return mask_img_bbox

display_array(compute_bbox_overlay(image, bbox_coords))
```

#### Output:

[image]

### 4. Conclusion

I think that `compute_bbox_overlay` is good enough and don't need to be further optimized. However, I'm genuinely interested if you have any idea to make `compute_bbox_coordinates` faster and really would like to focus on improving this function which be pretty slow when a large amount of cluster are in the image.

If you need any additional precision, I'll be glad to edit my post. I see this post more like a discussion than truely expecting a *turn-key* solution ;)

#### Performance Metrics:

Depending on the value of k, I have the following performance (for step 2 and 3 together, most of the time being performed in step 2).

- `k == 1`: 47 msecs => **nice and fast #Yeah**
- `k == 25`: 1.4 second => **from that point, it's already too much**
- `k == 100`: 8.8 seconds => **absolutely prohibitive, totally unusable**
- `k == 200`: 20.7 seconds => **waiting for quantum computing, might be faster...**

As you can see, there is room for improvement ;)

Comment: For part 1, your `k` parameter sounds like `eps` in the [DBSCAN](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html#sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN) algorithm. That might be useful

Comment: The part 1 is just a generator to give you a working example, however I dont use the algorithm detailed in part1, just here to give a reproducible example. However, I will have a look to DBSCAN, thanks @Tgsmith61591

Comment: Gotcha. I was under the impression you wanted to use that to detect points and classify groups. My mistake!

Comment: In very global ideas, I want to cluster the pixel according to a distance parameter and draw a bbox around the clusters. Very simple in principle, not so straightforward to get not incredibly slow if distance is large

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a computer vision library such as OpenCV, you can use the [distance transform](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/distance.htm) to do this. OpenCV [distanceTransform](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga8a0b7fdfcb7a13dde018988ba3a43042) calculates the distance to the closest zero pixel for each pixel of the source image. So, for your sample image, you can simply invert your source image, take the distance transform, threshold it and find the contours, then calculate their bounding boxes.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

im = cv2.imread('gzRYR.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# distance-transform
dist = cv2.distanceTransform(~gray, cv2.DIST_L1, 3)
# max distance
k = 10
bw = np.uint8(dist < k)
# remove extra padding created by distance-transform
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (k, k))
bw2 = cv2.morphologyEx(bw, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, kernel)
# clusters
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(bw2, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# draw clusters and bounding-boxes
i = 0
print(len(contours))
for cnt in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    cv2.rectangle(im, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.drawContours(im, contours, i, (255, 0, 0), 2)
    i += 1

plt.subplot(121); plt.imshow(im)
plt.subplot(122); plt.imshow(bw2)
```

[image: img]

Answer (score 1):

[dhanushka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51614354/7328782) does just the right thing. That answer uses a distance transform with L1 norm (which leads to a diamond-shaped unit circle). The L1 norm is relatively cheap to compute, but it still computes distances across the whole image, which is not necessary.

There is a way to speed this up a bit: use a morphological dilation with a square structuring element. The size of the structuring element indicates which dots should be considered to be in the same cluster, in the same way that the distance transform merges the dots into groups (actually the threshold of the distance transform is a dilation). However, using a square structuring element will make this operation very, very cheap: it can be computed using two passes through the image using less than 3 comparisons per output pixel in each pass. The cheapest implementation of the distance transform will use two passes through the image using 4 multiplications and additions per output pixel in each pass.